# gvim can't locate the Perl modules

Tags: perl, vim

I'm trying to write a function in gvim that would use the module `File::Path`.But
it alert me `"Can't locate File/Path.pm in @INC(@INC contains: .) at (eval 8) line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 8) line 1."` when gvim start.
I know it means gvim couldn't find my perl lib path.
So,my question was :
How to tell gvim the correct path to locate the Perl modules?I have tried to add `use lib'C:/Perl/lib';` but the problem continued.
Thank you~~~

```
if has("perl")
function! Make_dir()
    perl make_dir();
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call Make_dir()
perl <<EOF
use File::Path;
sub make_dir{
    my $bakup=$ENV{'HOME'}."/bakup" ;
    mkdir $bakup if not -e _;
    #VIM::SetOption("backup");
    #VIM::SetOption("backupdir=$bakup");
    #VIM::Msg($bakup);
    #todo....
}
EOF
endif
```

Comment: if your problem is `mkdir` you can use vim script internal function too. `:help mkdir`

Comment: also you can call mkdir from yourperl script `VIM::DoCommand("call mkdir('$bakup')")`

Comment: Is `perl -MFile::Path -e1` works in your shell ?

Comment: hi,sputnick,here is the output : `C:\WINDOWS\system32>perl -MFile::Path -e1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Comment: hi,ali,I think my problem is nothing to do with `mkdir` .Because it could works fine without `use ModuleName;` I'm not farmilar with vim script

Answer (score 2):

Did you "censor" your output, or does it really say just "`(@INC contains: .)`"? That would seem to indicate a bad installation of Perl. It should have a few more directories in there. It could indicate a permission problem, I imagine.

`use lib` doesn't work because Perl can't find `lib.pm` or any other module it comes with. `-I` should work though, but it would only be a bandaid fix.

Comment: Thank you,I could run perl script perfectly and it output the correct info about perl by type`perl -v` in console.So the installtion of Perl ought to be fine.

Comment: You're presuming the same `perl` is run in both cases, but you have not demonstrated that.

Comment: Also, `perl -v` doesn't use any modules.

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script:556
BTW,I tried the way on vim tips wiki also...but the problem continued

Comment: Is this an answer? If not try to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10959635/edit) your question.